# Is there any mention of ghosts who live outside the Hogwarts castle?

Tags: harry-potter, ghost

Hogwarts seems to house many ghosts but has it ever been mentioned in the narrative, of ghosts that reside outside the castle? At Beauxbatons and Durmstrang, for instance? Or at the Ministry? It's been a while since I read HP so I might have missed some obvious clues.

Rowena Ravenclaw/Grey Lady is one ghost I can think of who would have wanted to stay away from Hogwarts after running away with the diadem but she too returns back after her death. Though improbable, it lead me to believe that Hogwarts is the sole residence for ghosts until I came across [this](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts) on Pottermore.

> Hogwarts is the most heavily haunted dwelling place in Britain (and
>   this is against stiff competition, as there are more reported ghost
>   sightings/sensings on these damp islands than anywhere else in the
>   world).

But I can't make sense of the above sentence. Stiff competition from whom? Also, "damp islands" as in Hogwarts?

This, of course, means that Hogwarts is the preferred dwelling place for ghosts despite not being the sole one right?

I couldn't find this question on here but if it's a duplicate, please do mention.

Comment: '*Damp islands*' is a slightly snarky way of describing Great Britain. We get a lot of rain and talk about it a lot.

Comment: @Valorum Ooh thanks, one does learn something new everyday! Just to be clear, the Pottermore sentence means that despite there being loads of places in Britain which ghosts haunt, Hogwarts still takes the top spot, right?

Comment: Absolutely. It's the most haunted place in the UK and possibly the entire world

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, the [*'Wailing Widow'*](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wailing_Widow) and various other ghosts attended the Death-day celebration for Nearly-Headless Nick and traveled from outside the castle.

> "Not a bad turnout. **The Wailing Widow came all the way up from Kent…**
> It's nearly time for my speech, I'd better go and warn the orchestra…"
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

Answer (score 16):

In Chapter Eight of *Chamber of Secrets* when Nearly Headless Nick invites Harry to his deathday party he says:

> Friends will be coming from all over the country.

As these friends are ghosts, there are clearly ghosts all over the country.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a head throwing team that nearly-headless Nick wanted to participate. We don’t see them around Hogwarts after his deathday party so it’s safe to assume they are outside Hogwarts. I will provide the respective section later

Comment: You're talking about the Headless Hunt I presume. I don't remember much, was it mentioned that they came from outside?

Comment: @Matte - I don't remember a direct proof, however he did correspond with them via letters (he read a formal rejection letter to Harry Potter once). If they were local, I doubt he would need to resort to that.